# Sorting a map by values - keys

Tags: c++

I'm writing a code that counts the number of occurrences of each word in a file, and print out these words in order of number of occurrences. After each word, it prints its number of occurrences. Words occurring the same number of times in the file are listed in alphabetical order.

I don't know how to modify that code to get the words in order of number of occurrences, and that words occurring the same number of times in the file are listed in alphabetical order.

Limitations: I can use only headers like **`<iostream>`, `<map>`, `<string>`, `<fstream>` and `<utility>`**

Example of how it should work:

In:

```
one two three one two four two one two
```

Out:

```
four 1
three 1
one 3
two 4
```

By now, I've done something like that:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <map>
#include <string>
typedef std::map<std::string, int> StringIntMap;

void count_words(std::istream &in, StringIntMap &words)
{
    std::string text;
    while (in >> text)
    {
        ++words[text];
    }
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    std::ifstream in("readme.txt");
    StringIntMap words_map;
    count_words(in, words_map);

    for (StringIntMap::iterator it = words_map.begin(); it != words_map.end(); ++it)
    {
        std::cout << it->first << " " << it->second << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: `#include <algorithm>` and `#include <vector>` are off the table? Otherwise you could simply create a `std::vector<std::pair<const std::string, int>*>` containing pointers to the entries in the map and sort them using a custom comparison function.

Comment: you can use `std::map<int,std::map<std::string,int>>`, note that the inner `map` is simply a way to mimic `std::vector`. (or the whole to mimic `multimap`)

Comment: oh wait, `multimap` is also in `<map>`, then you can simply use that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution using `std::map` to perform the sorting.
Readability may be further improved by replacing `std::pair<string, int>` with a struct with a meaningful name.

```cpp
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <utility>

using std::cout;
using std::ifstream;
using std::map;
using std::pair;
using std::string;

struct Dummy {};

struct Compare {
  bool operator()(const pair<string, int> &p1,
                  const pair<string, int> &p2) const {
    if (p1.second < p2.second) {
      return true;
    } else if (p1.second > p2.second) {
      return false;
    } else {
      return p1.first < p2.first;
    }
  }
};

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  ifstream in("readme.txt");

  map<string, int> occurences;
  string word;
  while (in >> word) {
    occurences[word]++;
  }

  map<pair<string, int>, Dummy, Compare> sorted;
  for (const auto &p : occurences) {
    sorted.insert({p, Dummy{}});
  }
  for (const auto &p : sorted) {
    cout << p.first.first << ": " << p.first.second << "\n";
  }
}
```

Comment: if you use it this way might as well just use a `set`. I don't the point of this beyond trying really hard to use `map` whether it makes sense or not.

Comment: Sure, `set` is a more sensible choice. I opted to use `map` since `set` is not listed in the question.

Answer (score 0):

you can use [`std::multimap`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/multimap) to do the the sort.

```
int main()
{
    std::map<std::string,int> words_map;
    count_words(std::cin, words_map);
    
    std::multimap<int,std::string> frequency_map;

    for(auto& [word,freq]:words_map){
        frequency_map.insert({freq,word});
    }

    for(auto& [freq,word]:frequency_map){
        std::cout << word << ' ' << freq << '\n';
    }
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/Er7o8Wec1

Comment: Looks good, and works on the site, but why I see some errors from the 25 line(for loop) when I copy the code to Codeblock? The first one: error: expected unqualified-id before '[' token

Comment: @Constant This answer uses the [structed binding declaration](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/structured_binding) syntax, which is available starting from C++17. To use this language feature, you have to configure your IDE so that the compiler uses the C++17 standard.

Comment: @Constant if you don't have c++17, it's not that much different, just do `auto& pair:words_map` and unpack it by `auto& word=pair.first; auto& freq=pair.second;` (or simply use the pair direcly)

Comment: Right, it's on my side. I use c++11 cause can't use any higher. My teacher doesn't allow us, but anyway, thank you guys for help.